# MySQL server stopped working

Tags: data-recovery, mysql, innodb

Yesterday, out of the blue, the MySQL working as a backend for my private postfix server stopped working. No log entries, nothing, it just won't start. I reinstalled it and it worked until I copied the origanl databases to /var/lib/mysql. To be more exact, it fails as soon as I copy ibdata1.
Since it wasn't much data and it can be reconstructed, I don't have a dump. Is there any way to recover the data from the database binaries?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

```
You should be able to restore by copying them in your database folder.

You should do it while the server is not running.
```

Comment: As I said, that leads to the server not starting. Indeed, I now found a solution: http://chepri.com/mysql-innodb-corruption-and-recovery/ (This also includes a more precise description of my problem - I seem to have overlooked the error.log messages the first time)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters the same problem, I already found the solution. Sorry to have bothered you:
http://chepri.com/mysql-innodb-corruption-and-recovery/

May a mod can decide if this question is worth keeping or should be deleted.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions. I would suggest expanding this answer out to something more than a 'link only answer'. This will prevent link rot should the linked website ever move or go offline.